# Differential equations with complex coefficients/values

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

This is not a technical question, I'm just wondering if there is any natural system that can be modelled by a DE with complex coefficients? And another somewhat related question is: Is there any natural system that can be modelled by a complex $\textit{valued}$ DE.
Any examples would be a great starting point for me to understand this a bit better.